# Sum categorical feature labels across columns for given row, pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, counter

What would be a pythonic way of summing (same) label counts of categorical variables for each instance in a df?
For eg:

```
qualityOfLife_df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'Up', 'Up', 'Same'], 
                               ['B', 'Up', 'Down', 'Up'],
                                ['C', 'Down', 'Down', 'Down']],
                               columns = ['City', 'Crime', 'Pollution', 'Jobs'])
```

should give, after adding in the label count columns:

```
  City Crime Pollution  Jobs  nUp  nDown  nSame
0    A    Up        Up  Same    2      0      1
1    B    Up      Down    Up    2      1      0
2    C  Down      Down  Down    0      3      0
```

Thanks

Comment: This is classic example of the wide vs long dataset problem. Currently you have different indicators as named columns sharing same data values and then want to aggregate value counts as *new* columns. Best practice is to reshape source data to long format which is scalable and efficient and then run `groupby` value counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the `pd.Series.value_counts` function on each row and then after replacing the `nan`s with zero concatenate the counts to the second axis of your `dataframe`.

```
>>> counts = qualityOfLife_df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1)[['Up', 'Down', 'Same']].fillna(0)
>>> pd.concat((qualityOfLife_df, counts), axis=1)
  City Crime Pollution  Jobs   Up  Down  Same
0    A    Up        Up  Same  2.0   0.0   1.0
1    B    Up      Down    Up  2.0   1.0   0.0
2    C  Down      Down  Down  0.0   3.0   0.0
```

Also as mentioned in comment, you can use `astype(int)` to convert float numbers to integer. Which I'd recommend, for the sake of memory optimization, if you're dealing with larger data sets, use a smaller integer type like `np.int16` or `np.int8` based on the maximum number that counts can possibly hold.

```
>>> pd.concat((qualityOfLife_df, counts.astype(int)), axis=1)
  City Crime Pollution  Jobs  Up  Down  Same
0    A    Up        Up  Same   2     0     1
1    B    Up      Down    Up   2     1     0
2    C  Down      Down  Down   0     3     0
```

Comment: @jpp Fortunately we're not at subatomic level, thus I don't expect 0.5 count of anything ;).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use dummy variables for each column and then take their sum:

```
pd.get_dummies(qualityOfLife_df.loc[:, 'Crime':'Jobs']).groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[1], axis=1).sum()
Out: 
   Down  Same  Up
0     0     1   2
1     1     0   2
2     3     0   0
```

I'd expect this to be more efficient if you have large number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` from the standard library:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = pd.DataFrame(df[['Crime', 'Pollution', 'Jobs']].apply(Counter, axis=1).tolist())\
           .fillna(0).astype(int)

df = df.join(counts)

print(df)

  City Crime Pollution  Jobs  Down  Same  Up
0    A    Up        Up  Same     0     1   2
1    B    Up      Down    Up     1     0   2
2    C  Down      Down  Down     3     0   0
```